# How to reduce noise when using scharr filter?

Tags: python, opencv

I try to implement **Sharr filter + remove noise**. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

filename = sys.argv[1]
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 300000)
scale = 1
delta = 0
ddepth = cv2.CV_16S 
while(True):
       success, img = cap.read() 
       img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),0)       
       gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

       #Scharr filter
       scharr_grad_x = cv2.Scharr(gray,ddepth,1,0)
       scharr_grad_y = cv2.Scharr(gray,ddepth,0,1)
       scharr_abs_grad_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(scharr_grad_x)   
       scharr_abs_grad_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(scharr_grad_y)
       #remove noize after scharr filter
       scharr = np.hypot(scharr_abs_grad_x, scharr_abs_grad_y)
       mean = np.mean(scharr);
       scharr[scharr <= mean] = 0;
       scharr = cv2.add(scharr_abs_grad_x,scharr_abs_grad_y)
       cv2.imshow('scharr',scharr)
       if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I found idea with numpy. But I can't correct make solution.
 The result will be as on screenshots below.

[Sharr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akNXf.jpg)

[Scharr without noise I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj5gK.jpg)

How can I implement it in my code?

Comment: Please provide a running code sample and be sure to use the right indentation of code.

Comment: @linusg, hi. http://pastebin.com/raw/RRQ6Uwrw

Comment: Thanks, I've put it into your question. Please accept the edit.